# Keeping food warm: Do double duty with heated dinner plate and enameled cast iron sizzle "charger" plate?

Tags: temperature, cast-iron, heat, skillet

Will using both a heated dinner plate and an enameled cast iron sizzle plate as a charger (under the dinner plate) keep food warm for an appreciably longer time than simply heating the dinner plate or putting the dinner plate on a warmed metal-of-some-kind charger?  Or maybe even an enameled cast-iron trivet?

Note:

- I do not own and have never used cast iron of any kind. So though at first thought this seems a sensible idea, but maybe there are physics or other factors that negate the idea?
- I like my dinner plates. I do not want a dinner plate substitute (such as eating from the sizzle plate).

Comment: Sounds like overkill.  Why not just warm the dinner plates in the oven?

Comment: Plates? Are you saying the food gets cold *while eating*?

Comment: moscafj - Per the post, I am interested in EXTENDING the heat time of using traditional plate-heating methods. 

@Johannes_B, Yes, exactly. Even on a heated plate food gets cold while eating and, in my belief, is primarily due to locale (you gave a helpful comment about this https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/105723/why-does-food-get-cold-faster-in-some-locales-than-others ).