# Why does food get cold faster in some locales than others?

Tags: temperature, heat

I live in a dry climate at 7,000 feet where we experience a true four seasons. The temperature range can be vast from below 0 degrees farenheit to the high 90s and sometimes over 100.

I've noticed that regardless of the time of year, that food gets cold faster in my locale than in humid, lower elevation locales. This is true whether eating indoors with the furnace on or the air conditioner off, or when grilling outdoors.

Is this true only in my imagination, or is there a scientific explanation for it?

Comment: This is more of a physics question.

Comment: @Johannes_B much of cooking involves physics, your second comment is an answer.

Comment: I agree with @DebbieM. , there's no reason a bit of science put into context is very on-topic.

Comment: @Alchimista Please write up an answer. :-)

Comment: But it is not a real answer. Those are just principle of heat flow. Really doubt they can be discerned. We know already that colder and humid the air faster the cooling. Again humidity works in opposite direction. Humid air has high specific heat, so it prevents evaporation but still is an efficient coolant. Opposite for ice cream, that melts faster.

Comment: Wow, this is a head-twister for mere mortals (like me).